# Add change Listener on Marker

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, markers

How can I add modification Listener in the IMarker bounds? For example I have the red marker, which wraps the @Annotation. How can I get notification, when the "@Annotation" text get changed ? I want to modify/remove the marker by changing the text.

My main goal is to change the marker when the text in the box get changed. Is it possible ?

[image: Marker Example]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. You have to implement the `IResourceChangeListener` interface, register it in the workspace to listen for changes in markers, and call the findMarkerDeltas() when an event arrives.

You can get more info [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resAdv_events.htm).

Comment: The IResourceChangeListener works only when I save the document, not by typing.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to implement the *IPartListener2* ([JavaDoc](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IPartListener2.html)) and override the method `partInputChanged`.
I didn't find any way to register listener on a specified marker.

Comment: When you implement the IResourceChangeListener, you can get the marker deltas for any specific type with `event.findMarkerDeltas("you marker type", false);`